# Spring Security custom login authentication not working

Tags: java, spring-security

I'm trying to implement spring security custom login. When it was running on the standard spring form it worked well to login and authenticate the user. But now that I changed it to a custom login page, it's not working anymore. Below is the code. When I type the user and password and click submit, it stays in the login page without authenticating the user.
What's wrong in the code?

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EntityScan(basePackages="projetos.model")
@ComponentScan(basePackages= {"projetos.*"})
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages= {"projetos.repository"})
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableWebMvc
public class PessoaApplication implements WebMvcConfigurer{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(PessoaApplication.class, args);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("/login");
        registry.setOrder(Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE);
        
    }

}


@Service
@Transactional
public class ImplementacaoUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService{


    @Autowired
    private UsuarioRepository usuarioRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        Usuario usuario = usuarioRepository.selectUsuarioPorLogin(username);
        
        if (usuario == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Usuario não foi encontrado.");         
        }
        
        return new User(usuario.getLogin(), usuario.getSenha(),
                usuario.isEnabled(), true,
                true, true,
                usuario.getAuthorities());
    }

}


@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebConfigSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{
    
    @Autowired
    private ImplementacaoUserDetailsService implementacaoUserDetailsService;
    
    

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf()
        .disable() 
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/gerente/**").hasAnyRole("GERENTE", "ADMIN")
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/diretor/**").hasAnyRole("DIRETOR", "ADMIN")
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/").permitAll() 
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and().formLogin().permitAll() 
        .loginPage("/login")
        //.defaultSuccessUrl("") 
        .failureUrl("/login?error=true")
        .and().logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
        .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"));
        
    }
    
    
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        
        auth.userDetailsService(implementacaoUserDetailsService)
        .passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: this can not be answered since the problem is in the front end and you havn't posted your front end code. Keep that in mind until next time you ask a question, we usually need the full picture.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `loginProcessingUrl()` to your configuration.

`loginPage("...")` instructs Spring Security when authentication is required, redirect the browser to that URL

`loginProcessingUrl("...")` is the URL to submit the username and password to.

Comment: The page I have the username and password fields is called login.html. Understand that is the default name used by spring security and loginProcessingUrl would just be needed if you are using a different name for the login page. Isn't that the case? Anyway, I added .loginProcessingUrl("/login") and still didn't authenticate.

Comment: I found the problem. I was using upper case in the first letter of the word login in the following code, while it should be lower case. `<form th:action="@{/login}" method="post">` Thanks.